# set contentSize equal to the bottom of a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

In the interface builder i've created a `UIViewController` which contain a `UIScrollView` with an image and two labels like this. I would like to set the `UIScrollViews` `ContentSize` to be equal to the bottom of the fullText, but at the moment it does not seem to work, since i can't scroll even though the fullText is covering more than the screen size.

Here is my `viewWillAppear` code.

```
    newsImage?.image = newsObject?.imageLink
    newsImage?.clipsToBounds = true
    titleText?.text = formatString(newsObject!.title as! String)
    titleText?.font = UIFont(name: "PT Sans", size: 25)
    titleText?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.frame.width
    titleText?.numberOfLines = 0


    fullText?.text = formatString(newsObject!.summary as! String)
    fullText?.font = UIFont(name: "PT Sans", size: 16)
    fullText?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.frame.width
    fullText?.numberOfLines = 0
    scrollView?.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width,     self.fullText!.frame.origin.y + self.fullText!.frame.height)
```

[image]

Comment: have you added any constraints? you aren't running a layout

Comment: A tip - you can use `CGRectGetMaxY(self.fullText!.frame)` when setting `scrollView`'s `contentSize`.

Otherwise, please provide a bit more code - how is the scroll view set up? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Replace your code in viewDidAppear. It might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `contentSize` doesn't really work with autolayout. The best solution you can do is to create constraints that will limit the content height. You don't have to use any code at all.

You need:

1. Vertical constraint from top of the `scrollView` to `image`
2. Vertical constraint for `image` height.
3. Vertical constraint from `image` to `titleText`
4. Vertical constraint from `titleText` to `fullText`.
5. Vertical constraint from `fullText` to bottom of the `scrollView`.

Then the content height will be calculated automatically.

Setting up width is a bit more complicated because you always want the width of the `scrollView` to be equal to the screen width. The simplest solution is to take one view, add constraint for its width, connect the constraint as an outlet and set its `.constant` to the screen size (`UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds`).

In general it is preferred to do most of the view setup in IB and not in code. For example, you can set up label fonts in IB, too.

Comment: i've added a image just for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

use this code for height:

```
[text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil].size.height
```

Comment: I'm not sure this can be used in Swift?

Comment: You can use this swift method to calculate height of text view : self.fullText?.text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: DBL_MAX),
            options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.fullText?.font],
            context: nil).size.height